# Percolation and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am working on a Percolation java program. I have implemented the following Percolation.java file and am running into an error when testing it with certain input files, as described below.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;

public class Percolation {
    private int n;
    private WeightedQuickUnionUF verify;
    private WeightedQuickUnionUF solution;
    private int sink;
    private int source = 0;
    private boolean[][] grid;
    private int openSites = 0;
    private int length;

    // creates n-by-n grid, with all sites initially blocked
    public Percolation(int n) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.length = n;
        this.grid = new boolean[length][length];

        this.sink = (length * length) + 1;
        verify = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(length * length + 2);
        solution = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(length * length + 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            verify.union(encode(0, i), source);
            solution.union(encode(0, i), source);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            verify.union(encode(n - 1, j), sink);
        }
    }

    // opens the site (row, col) if it is not open already
    public void open(int row, int col) {

        grid[row][col] = true;
        openSites++;
        if ((row - 1) >= 0 && isOpen(row - 1, col)) {
            verify.union(encode(row, col), encode(row - 1, col));
            solution.union(encode(row, col), encode(row - 1, col));
        }
        if ((row + 1) < length && isOpen(row + 1, col)) {
            verify.union(encode(row, col), encode(row + 1, col));
            solution.union(encode(row, col), encode(row + 1, col));
        }
        if ((col - 1) >= 0 && isOpen(row, col - 1)) {
            verify.union(encode(row, col), encode(row, col - 1));
            solution.union(encode(row, col), encode(row, col - 1));
        }
        if ((col + 1) < length && isOpen(row, col + 1)) {
            verify.union(encode(row, col), encode(row, col + 1));
            solution.union(encode(row, col), encode(row, col + 1));
        }

    }

    // is the site (row, col) open?
    public boolean isOpen(int row, int col) {
        return grid[row][col];
    }

    // is the site (row, col) full?
    public boolean isFull(int row, int col) {
        return solution.find(source) == solution.find(encode(row, col));
    }

    // returns the number of open sites
    public int numberOfOpenSites() {
        return openSites;
    }

    // does the system percolate?
    public boolean percolates() {
        return verify.find(0) == verify.find(sink);
    }

    // An integer ID (1...n) for site (i, j).
    private int encode(int row, int col) {
        int number = length * row + 1 + col;
        return number;
    }

    // unit testing (required)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = args[0];
        In in = new In(filename);
        int n = in.readInt();
        Percolation perc = new Percolation(n);
        while (!in.isEmpty()) {
            int i = in.readInt();
            int j = in.readInt();
            perc.open(i, j);
        }
        StdOut.println(perc.numberOfOpenSites() + " open sites");
        if (perc.percolates()) {
            StdOut.println("percolates");
        }
        else {
            StdOut.println("does not percolate");
        }

        // Check if site (i, j) optionally specified on the command line
        // is full.
        if (args.length == 3) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            int j = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            StdOut.println(perc.isFull(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I test the code using certain input files, I receive error messages such as the following:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 8
Percolation.isOpen(Percolation.java:63)
TestPercolation.checkIsOpen(TestPercolation.java:122)
TestPercolation.checkIsOpen(TestPercolation.java:105)
TestPercolation.check(TestPercolation.java:177)
TestPercolation.checkFile(TestPercolation.java:198)
TestPercolation.test1(TestPercolation.java:659)
TestPercolation.main(TestPercolation.java:963)


java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 25 out of bounds for length 25
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
```

What in my code could be causing this? In other words, where is the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: What does your input file look like?  What are you passing for `args`?

Comment: Does the assignment say that 1-based indexes will be used? Because Java arrays (like most languages) are 0-based, and the indexes for length 8 would be 0 through 7, inclusive. It looks like it's the test driver (presumably not your code) which is calling your `isOpen` method with a value of 8 when the length is 8. It is possible you should be subtracting 1 from the values it passes to you. I would double check the documentation.

Comment: There is only one thing that jumps out at me as a possible error in your code. Method `open` says that it opens the site "if it is not open already", but it increments `openSites` regardless of whether it was open or not, which would result in an incorrect count if it was already open. Setting the value in the `grid` to `true` would only be redundant if it was already open, but incrementing the value would be wrong, and performing the subsequent `union` operations may be, too; I don't know what they do.

Comment: To avoid that, you could return immediately at the beginning of `open` if that site on the grid is already open.